# Cassandra C++ connector: Address changed

Tags: c++, cassandra

I'm having some trouble with Cassandra's C++ connector. It is set to connect to a cluster (e.g. 10.0.0.10 and 10.0.0.11). One of the hosts has changed address (it's now 10.1.1.10). I've already updated cassandra's configuration, removed 10.0.0.11 from the peers table. Nodetool is already showing the correct cluster configuration.

Yet, the C++ connector keeps complaining about connecting to 10.0.0.11. I have no idea where to find that. Since no production data has been involved (yet), I've destroyed all the data directories and recreated keyspace. Still, this appears to be cached somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `broadcast_rpc_address` in the file `cassandra.yaml` was set to the old IP address.

This was enough to make the client search for the old IP address. This happens only when the host 10.0.0.10 was the contact point.